# Rails javascript window.location not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to route to a different page in Rails using Javascript (Coffeescript).

This is my code:

```
  # go to edit page
  serverused =  window.location.host
  newurl = serverused + '/sites/' + node.id + '/edit'
  alert newurl
  window.location = newurl
  alert window.location
  return
```

The `alert new url` = "localhost:3000/sites/2/edit"

The `alert window.location` (which it shouldn't even get to) shows: "localhost:3000/sites/tree#node-5" - which is the current url.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newurl` probably needs a `http://` or `https://` in front of it. Or you can grab the protocol from the current location:

```
newurl = window.location.protocol + '//' + serverused + '/sites/' + node.id + '/edit'
```

You can also use string interpolation in Coffeescript (requires double quotes):

```
newurl = "#{window.location.protocol}//#{serverused}/sites/#{node.id}/edit"
```

Comment: You are right: `window.location = 'google.com'` fails whereas `window.location = 'http://google.com` works